# Detect Whether to use EST or EDT for New York Time

Tags: c#

I'm parsing a list of dates which are of New York local time and creating DateTimeOffsets with the correct timezone. However, I am not sure how to detect if the zone should be EST or EDT. 
For example, the below takes a New York time and then converts into Hong Kong time. However, it will be incorrect during periods of EDT.

```
var timeStamp = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");        
DateTimeOffset nyTime = new DateTimeOffset(timeStamp, tz.BaseUtcOffset);

var hkTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");        

DateTimeOffset convertedDToffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(nyTime , timeZone);

var hkTime = convertedDToffset.DateTime;
```

However, this will give the incorrect time when EDT is prevalent. How can I automatically detect which to use? (I'm really looking for a New York Timezone....)

Comment: Just don't use `tz.BaseUtcOffset` - ask the time zone to convert the value itself, e.g. with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, or perhaps `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`. Without knowing what `timeStamp` is, it's hard to give a very concrete answer here. A [mcve] would help us to help you more. As a personal plug, my [Noda Time project](https://nodatime.org) is designed to make things like this a lot harder to get wrong (and easier to express correctly).

Comment: It is significantly easier and less error prone to use the DateTimeOffset type, when you need to be dealing with multiple time zones. If this is for a website or application that can be accessed in multiple time zones, store and process DateTimeOffsets in your application and offload the conversion to local time to the client, so you're never wrong.

Comment: I edited the question to provide a working snippet. The issue is when I'm using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime the time I'm passing in is already incorrect as I'm unsure of whether the prevalent local time in NY was EST or EDT.

Comment: You've still provided incomplete information though - we don't know what `dateStr` is, or your expected output, or your actual output. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In case you have input date as local NY time you can try this.

Tested with corner case on march 8, 2020 at 2:00 AM

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var hkTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");

        var timeStamp = DateTime.Parse("8/3/2020 0:59:59");
        PrintUtc(timeStamp, est);
        Console.WriteLine("To HK {0}", ToHkDateTime(timeStamp, est, hkTimeZone));

        timeStamp = DateTime.Parse("8/3/2020 1:59:59");
        PrintUtc(timeStamp, est);
        Console.WriteLine("To HK {0}", ToHkDateTime(timeStamp, est, hkTimeZone));

        timeStamp = DateTime.Parse("8/3/2020 3:00:00");
        PrintUtc(timeStamp, est);

        Console.WriteLine("To HK {0}", ToHkDateTime(timeStamp, est, hkTimeZone));
    }

    private static void PrintUtc(DateTime timeStamp, TimeZoneInfo est)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if (est.IsDaylightSavingTime(timeStamp))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IsDaylightSavingTime");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("GetUtcOffset: {0}", est.GetUtcOffset(timeStamp));
        Console.WriteLine(timeStamp.ToString("F"));


        Console.WriteLine("ToUtc {0}",
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timeStamp, est));
    }

    private static DateTime ToHkDateTime(DateTime timeStamp, TimeZoneInfo est, TimeZoneInfo hkTimeZone)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timeStamp, est),
            hkTimeZone);
    }
```